# Using hardhat-deploy plugin for deploying OpenZeppelin upgradable contracts

Tags: openzeppelin, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

What is the correct way to deploy OpenZeppelin upgradable contracts?
OpenZeppelin upgrdable contracts have default `initialize()` function which is automatically called by the `hardhat-upgrades` plugin.

There is no automatic call from `hardhat-deploy`, only post-upgrade method, e.g.:

```
const deployResult = await deploy('ContractX', {
    from: deployer,
    proxyContract: 'OpenZeppelinTransparentProxy',
    method: 'postUpgrade',
    args: []
  });
```

Should I deploy the contracts first through the scripts in the `deploy` folder and then call `initialize()` functions from some script outside `deploy` folder? Or is there a way to incorporate calling `initialize()` function from the deploy folder itself?

Comment: You might want to use [openzeppelin-upgrades](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades) rather than hardhat-deploy.

Comment: Thanks but hardhat-deploy is much more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

```
const deployResult = await deploy('ContractX', {
    from: deployer,
    proxy: {
        proxyContract: 'OpenZeppelinTransparentProxy',
        execute: {
            methodName: "initialize",
            args: []
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: add more information about the answer please

Answer (score 0):

a more complex example:

```
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from 'hardhat/types';
import { DeployFunction } from 'hardhat-deploy/types';

const func: DeployFunction = async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  const { deployments, getNamedAccounts } = hre;
  const { deploy } = deployments;
  const { deployer, proxyAdminOwner } = await getNamedAccounts();

  const DataTypes = await deploy('DataTypes', {
    from: deployer,
  });

  const Errors = await deploy('Errors', {
    from: deployer,
  });

  const MintingLogic = await deploy('MintingLogic', {
    from: deployer,
  });

  const ValidationLogic = await deploy('ValidationLogic', {
    from: deployer,
  });

  await deploy('ContractName', {
    from: deployer,
    contract: 'ContractName',
    log: true,
    proxy: {
      owner: proxyAdminOwner,
      proxyContract: 'OptimizedTransparentProxy',
      execute: {
        init: {
          methodName: 'initialize',
          args: [],
        },
        onUpgrade: {
          methodName: 'postUpgrade',
          args: [],
        },
      },
    },
    libraries: {
      Errors: Errors.address,
      DataTypes: DataTypes.address,
      ValidationLogic: ValidationLogic.address,
      MintingLogic: MintingLogic.address,
    },
  });
};

export default func;
func.tags = ['ContractName'];
```

If you want more information don't hesitate to ask specific questions. There is too much to unpack here to explain it all

Comment: What are these methods? 'initialize'. 'postUpgrade'. Are they supposed to be on the implementation contract or proxy contract, what if you dont have a need for them?